# atr onmouseover to Raphaël.js vars created in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, raphael, onmouseover

Hope anyone could help.

I've got a huge amount of paths from svg file (showing only a few here) which I store in an array to dynamically create them on Raphael paper.

```
var paths = "M539.99,181v95.141h-0.12L509.521,181H539.99zdivideM539.99,276.511v84.85h-30.41L539.99,276.511zdivideM539.99,85.021V181h-30.47L539.99,85.021"; // string with paths from svg file. Much much bigger in real code
var pathsArray = paths.split("divide"); // putting all paths in an array
```

Everything works until I try to assign an attribute to a path in a onmouseover function inside a for loop. Nothing happens. And no error messages in the console.

```
var currentPath = window['section' + i];
currentPath.node.onmouseover = function() {  
    this.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
    currentPath.attr("fill", "#ccc"); // <-- THIS PART DOESNT WORK
}
```

I also tried it this way:

```
window['section' + i].attr("fill", "#ccc");
```

which gives me an error message: 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window['section' + i].attr')

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var paths = "M539.99,181v95.141h-0.12L509.521,181H539.99zdivideM539.99,276.511v84.85h-30.41L539.99,276.511zdivideM539.99,85.021V181h-30.47L539.99,85.021"; // string with paths from svg file. Much much bigger in real code
var pathsArray = paths.split("divide"); // putting all paths in an array 

var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 1000, 1000);

for (var i=0;i<pathsArray.length;i++)
{ 

var currentPath = window['section' + i];

currentPath = paper.path(pathsArray[i]);
currentPath.attr("fill", "#f00");
currentPath.attr("stroke", "#fff");
currentPath.node.onmouseover = function() {  
    this.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
    currentPath.attr("fill", "#ccc"); // <-- THIS PART DOESNT WORK
}

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *this* keyword, also according to [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.mouseover) there is a built in mouseover event. So the following should also work:

```
currentPath.mouseover(function() {  
    this.node.style.cursor = 'pointer';  // using 'node' property to get access to DOM element
    this.attr("fill", "#ccc"); // 'this' should refer to Raphael element
});
```

Even though currentPath was inside the handler function, it was always taking the value of the last 'currentPath' in loop.